# Finding the index of each element in list containing duplicated values

Tags: python, list

---

Hello,
Let's say I have a list called `values` that contains some dupliated elements `[330, 210, 130, 60, 0, 240, 280, 1300, 740, 640, 520, 430, 240, 240, 240, 200, 200]`. I want to get the index of each element even it's the duplicated ones.
Here is what I did

```
l = []
for item in values:
    if item < t_max:
        l.append(values.index(item))
```

but it gives the following result

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
10
11
5
5
5
15
15
```

Any idea how to preceed? Thank you.

Comment: What is `t_max`? Also, your question is unclear. If you want the index of each element, why do you need conditional statement.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @PCM t_max is a threshold value

Comment: @balderman the expected output is the index of each element in the list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `enumerate` instead:

```
for index, item in enumerate(values):
    if item < t_max:
        l.append(index)
```

Your code doesn't work because `index` takes the first occurrence of a value in a list, but in your list they're duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)

value = [330, 210, 130, 60, 0, 240, 280, 1300, 740, 640, 520, 430, 240, 240, 240, 200, 200]

for idx, v in enumerate(value):
    dct[v].append(idx)
    
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {330: [0],
             210: [1],
             130: [2],
             60: [3],
             0: [4],
             240: [5, 12, 13, 14],
             280: [6],
             1300: [7],
             740: [8],
             640: [9],
             520: [10],
             430: [11],
             200: [15, 16]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your tmax as sample 200

```
data = [330, 210, 130, 60, 0, 240, 280, 1300, 740, 640, 520, 430, 240, 240, 240, 200, 200]

l = []

for index, item in enumerate(data):
    if item < 200:
        l.append(index)
        print(index,item)

print(l)
```

will give

```
2 130
3 60
4 0
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] in lst[:i]]
```

Or better use a dictionary:

```
d = dict()
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    d[value] = d.get(value, []) + [index]
```

object d will refer to:

```
{330: [0], 210: [1], 130: [2], 60: [3], 0: [4], 240: [5, 12, 13, 14], 280: [6], 1300: [7], 740: [8], 640: [9], 520: [10], 430: [11], 200: [15, 16]}
```